# How to change default className of the material-ui Textfield?

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, classname

I am building a multi page form in reactjs using the material Ui framework. I have created different components for every page. Now at one point I have to add dynamic Textfield on button click. I am able to add the Textfield however when I try to change the value of the field a problem arises.

```
handleChangeDynamic = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.className)
        if(["vid", "vst", "vet"].includes(e.target.className)){
            console.log("in if")
            let v = [...this.state.v]
            v[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.className] = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
            this.setState({ v }, () => console.log(this.state.v))
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("in else")
            this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value.toUpperCase()})
        }
    };
```

This is the code that handles the change of a dynamic field. It uses the 'className' property to decide whether the field is dynamic or not.

```
                       <TextField
                        className="vst"
                        label="Alarm clock"
                        type="time"
                        defaultValue= "00:00"
                        variant = "outlined"
                        style = {{width : 300}}
                        name = {vstId}
                        data-id={index}
                        id={vstId}
                        value={v[index].name}
                      />
```

I am using this material Ui Textfield. However instead of detecting the className as "vst", It takes the className of the Mui Textfield and goes into the else part of the handleDynamicChange method.
How do I fix this? I do not wish to change the  to normal . Is there any other way?
Please help. this is very important.

Comment: Are you simply trying to toggle a classname on an element?

Answer (score 1):

Classnames can be given to MUI Text fields by using `inputProps` Prop of `TextField` component.

Like this -

```
<TextField
      id="sample"
      label="Sample Text Field"
      inputProps={{ className: "test" }}
    />
```

This will add `test` as an additional className to the  component along with `MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input`.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get 3 classNames - MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input test, How do I select just the 'test' from it? Because if I don't single out test it again goes into the 'else'    part of the function.

Comment: You can do something like this - `e.target.className.split(" ").find(item => ["vid", "vst", "test"].indexOf(item) > -1)`

Comment: 1/2 
Thank you for this, however after singling out the 'test' className I realised this wont work either because although it now enters the "if" part of the code, when it comes to setting the value that is this line - 
v[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.className]  = e.target.value.toUpperCase(), 
it needs the entire original className to set the value. So, I replaced  
if(["vid", "vst", "vet"].includes(e.target.className)) with 
if(["MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input vid", "vst", "vet"].includes(e.target.className)).

Comment: 2/2 
But now it cannot retrieve the ID required to set the value in v[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.className]. I can't understand why. It would be great if you could help!